# Trying to build PDF reader using MuPDF library, app crashing while opening PDF

Tags: android, android-library, aar, mupdf, .so

Good Day,
I'm trying to build PDF reader using MuPDF.
Everytime when I try opening pdf in app its showing `libmupdf_java.so` not found and application crashed. I'm using mupdf.aar bundle, I opened bundle & checked found libmupdf_java.so in it.
created `jniLibs` folder in main & copied `armeabi-v7a` & `x86` .so files in it but still facing same issue. How to sort it? I'm stuck here from many weeks. please help me.
I'm using samsung S10+ for android app simulation.

**LOGCAT**

```
2022-05-17 17:32:25.140 7620-7620/ak.wp.meto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ak.wp.meto, PID: 7620
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libmupdf_java.so" not found
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
        at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.<clinit>(MuPDFCore.java:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDdfY.png)

You add them to `jniLibs` directory under `src/main`. And it will work.